# jqplot not evaluating string

Tags: php, jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot and have constructed an array with the following PHP code

```
if($fiveRes){
    $lastNum = mysql_num_rows($fiveRes);

    $testarray = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fiveRes, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $testarray[] = array($row['GameDate'],  floatval($row['WKP']));
    }

    echo json_encode($testarray);

}
```

This code outputs the correct code that I need to insert into the jqplot function.  Here is the array generated by the code above:

```
[["2011-12-24",0],["2011-12-19",14],["2011-12-08",22],["2011-12-04",14],["2011-11-27",12]]
```

So currently i'm printing this array to the screen, and then using jQuery .text() to capture the string and place it inside a variable.  I can echo out the var that I assigned the array string to and it works correctly, however when I pass it into the jqplot function it does nothing.

```
var p1array = $('.col.first .parray').text();

alert(p1array); //Alerts the correct array formatted like above.

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('jqplot0', [p1array], {
          title:'Last 5 Fantasy Points',
          axes:{
            xaxis:{
              renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
              tickOptions:{
                formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d'
              } 
            },
            yaxis:{
              tickOptions:{
                formatString:''
                }
            }
          },
          highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
          },
          cursor: {
            show: false
          }
      });
```

To make it even more complicated, if I copy the string that the PHP generates and I hardcode it into a variable in JS it works. Any ideas why the jqplot plugin won't evaluate the string I get from using `$(this).text();`.

Here is the jQplot example i'm modeling after: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/cursor-highlighter.php

Comment: I don't know why the text() is not working but Have you tried/or is there any problem using p1array = <?php echo $php_string_you_created;?>;

Comment: what happens if you use p1array without the brackets?  ie var plot1 = $.jqplot('jqplot0', p1array, {...

Comment: Tried without the brackets and I get the same result

Comment: @HappyApe Does that mean I would have to move my JS inside of the PHP file?

Comment: hmm good question - yes, I tested it with js in php - but I recon its something to do with type-casting when you use text() method

Comment: Test this -> craete <input id=arraystring type=hidden value="php string value" /> then var p1array = $('#arraystring').val();

Comment: Not resolved, but here is a jsfiddle to depict the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/rDMea/

Comment: @HappyApe I tried adding the hidden input, but it's not working.

Comment: Added more PHP code including the json_encode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this method helped me solve this problem. Instead of using jQuery to access the printed variable I inserted a little bit of javascript at the bottom of my PHP page to capture the local variable in PHP and then used that to pass into the jQplot function.

[Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Answer (score 0):

Use [p1array] directly with out braces and try... it should work just like p1array

Comment: jQplot uses that syntax, it does not matter if the square brackets are around it I tried.

Comment: can you try var p1array = eval('{' + $('.col.first .parray').text() + '}'); this might help you out ....... hope so